# How to debug a Firebase authentication rule?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Within Firebase, I've implemented a rule to restrict access to a node to the user that's currently logged on.  The node looks like this:

```
{
    "app": {
        "my_team": {
            "a_really_long_uid_string": {
                "Lionel_Messi" = true,
                "Christiano_Ronaldo" = true
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and I've created the following rule (based on the online Firebase documentation), which should mean a logged in user can see only their own data (i.e. no other user's data).

```
{
    "rules": {
        "my_team": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My client environment is in Swift and I've made a simple test routine,

```
func testAuthentication() {
    print("test: \(uid)")
    FirebaseRef.child("my_team").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        print("test2: \(snapshot)")
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the first print in the console ("test: a_really_long_uid_string") but don't get the second print statement.

If I change the rule to restrict access to any logged in users, I get both print statements in the XCode console.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "my_team": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's up or how I can troubleshoot this?  I'm wondering if either auth.uid or $uid are nil or something on the server, which could be a reason for access being denied.

Comment: It could be that "a_really_long_uid_string" is different from the uid of the current session in your device. Could you verify that both uids are the same? Also, did you verify the security rule with the simulator? If so, did you get the same error?

Comment: I got it to work eventually by changing my client to look at {my_team/a_really_long_uid_string}. It seems the client needs to pass the variable value being used for authorization in addition to auth.uid being correct.